# How to copy a deployed application in heroku?

Tags: java, mysql, heroku, web-deployment

I have a `App1` application deployed on Heroku with database MySQL with the name `Bank1` and I wonder if there is any way to make an identical copy of the application including the database also MySQL named `Bank2` so that it already be deployed and running with the name `App2` regardless of my `App1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run [Heroku Fork](https://blog.heroku.com/heroku-fork):

```
heroku fork -a App1 App2
```

Comment: Hello codefinger, thank you so much for your help. It was exactly what I needed to do. Have a great weekend!